# hasClass not working when added dynamically

Tags: jquery

Trying to learn javascript and jquery, so be easy on me please.

Problem is, when i click on MENU, menu shows up but when i click BODY, it doesnt disappear. Why?

```
<div class="menu">MENU</div>
<nav class="hide-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

$('.menu').on('click', function(){
  $('nav').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
});

if ( $('nav').hasClass('show-nav') ) {
  $('body').on('click', function(){
    $(nav).removeClass('show-nav');
  });
}
```

Comment: You can see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Kayahan/2kr1ftvs/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the check for 'show-nav' inside the event handler.  You also need to add stopPropagation to to your menu click handler.  Without this, the body click handler will also be called and hide the menu after it's displayed.

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(event) {
  $('nav').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
  event.stopPropagation();
});


$('body').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($('nav').hasClass('show-nav')) {
    $('nav').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kr1ftvs/14/

Comment: The problem with that is that any subsequent events would not triggered.

Comment: Thanx a lot for explanation Barbara, i think i got the logic now. I really need more experience about javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't within the listener, thus it is only ran as it loads and then never again. So it's technically working, but it doesn't do what you want.

Instead, you want something like:

```
$('body').on('click,function(){
    if($('nav').hasClass('show-nav')){
        $('nav').removeClass('show-nav');
        $('nav').addClass('hide-nav');
    }
});
```

Edit: That is, replace the if ( $('nav').hasClass... bit with the code above

Comment: Thanx a lot! I've been working on this for hours... So, .on is listener right?